# Full api wmplib.windowsmediaplayer c#

Tags: c#, windows-media-player

I am a beginner in C#. I'm trying to create a simple audio player.

```js
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
wplayer.URL = "my_sound.mp3";
wplayer.controls.stop();
```

I searched full API about **WindowsMediaPlayer** but found only https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564585(v=vs.85).aspx

Please give me api link to MS library

Comment: Does the control documented there not work for you? What specifically are you looking for, or what's the particular problem?

Comment: I want change audio position

Comment: Ah, perfect. See my answer. (In the future, make sure to ask a *specific* question, as suggested in [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).)

Answer (score 1):

The full API documentation for the `WindowsMediaPlayer` control can be found [on MSDN here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms930695.aspx).

To answer the specific question you asked in the comments: Set the [`CurrentPosition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms910018.aspx) property on the media player control to seek. The value is a `double`, representing the seconds after the start of the media, so `95` corresponds to 1:35 (m:s), for example.